# PHP7.1 install failed when

Tags: php, php-7.1

I used the command -

```
 curl -# https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.1
```

Received this as the last output before it returned to shell.  Does it mean the install went OK or something needs to be corrected?

```
"Executing post-install script /tmp/7.1-10.10-frontenddev-post-install
Create symlink /usr/local/php5/entropy-php.conf /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
Restarting Apache
AH00526: Syntax error on line 20 of /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf:
Invalid command 'LockFile', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"
```

Thanks

Comment: Which OS are you trying to install it?

Comment: osx? use brew to install it.

Comment: OSX 10.11  - ok will try with brew